# How can I paste "my directory/*.class" to cp?

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, quotes

I have a shell script that should copy all class files from one directory to another (and then later do something else with the files). The problem is that the directory can contain blanks, and as soon as I add quotes ("") around my argument the *.class doesn't resolve. I have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the source directory is stored in $1

# create temp dir to copy files into
tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d)

# copy files:
cp "$1/*.class" "tmp_dir"
```

I get an error that "my directory/*.class" is no file or directory. If I run this by hand:

```
cp my\ directory/*.class
```

everything works fine. But if I run this (no matter if by hand or from the script) it fails:

```
cp "my directory/*.class"
```

I already tried to replace `"` by `'`, but it doesn't help.

How can I resolve `*.class`, or how can I escape the argument so that this works?

Comment: Quote the variable but not the `*`. `"$1"/*.class`

Comment: @EtanReisner has the better answer, but you could also take another step to escape the spaces. Something like `cp $(echo $1 | sed 's/ /\\ /g')/*.class $TMP_DIR`

Comment: @MicahSmith, no, that won't work (because expansion results go direct to string-splitting; they aren't parsed for syntax such as escape characters). See BashFAQ #50 for more details: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: By the way -- if you aren't exporting `TMP_DIR`, it'd be better to use a lower-case name for it, to make it clear that you aren't trying to overwrite the environment variable `TMPDIR` (which several programs use by default). Using `tmpdir` as the name avoids the ambiguity.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It was only an example, I normally use lowercase variables. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quote the wildcard itself:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
cp -- "$1"/*.class "$tmpdir"
```